# how to fix html/CSS alignment and formatting issue of a form attachment?

Tags: html, css, forms, attachment

I want to add an attachment for my HTML form. But I have some CSS and formatting issues with my code. There is a difference between expected output and actual output. Please help me to fix the CSS issues. Thank you

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-5 col-form-label">attachment</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="myfile" name="myfile"><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VdO7.png)

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUg3D.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your CSS code. It will be better if you please provide the CSS code of the HTML you have provided so to understand the situation better.